# Excel Range.FillDown using EPPlus

Tags: excel, epplus

How can I perform a FillDown operation on ExcelRange using EPPlus?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.filldown

Comment: If you already have the data in .net/code, why not just do the work youself with a loop?  If you truly need to run it in Excel on start up you will have to create an XLSM with VBA instead which can be tricky depending on user security settings.  Might want to post more detail on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
            //create a new ExcelPackage
            using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage())
            {
                //create 2 WorkSheets
                ExcelWorksheet worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet 1");
                ExcelWorksheet worksheet2 = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet 2");

                //set the calculation mode to manual
                excelPackage.Workbook.CalcMode = ExcelCalcMode.Manual;

                //fill cell data with a loop, note that row and column indexes start at 1
                for (int i = 1; i <= 25; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
                    {
                        worksheet.Cells[i, j].Value = (i + j) - 1;
                        worksheet2.Cells[i, j].Value = (i + j) - 1;
                    }
                }

                //set the total value of cells in range A1 - A25 into A27
                worksheet.Cells["A27"].Formula = "=SUM(A1:A25)";

                //set the number of cells with content in range C1 - C25 into C27
                worksheet.Cells["C27"].Formula = "=COUNT(C1:C25)";

                //fill column K with the sum of each row, range A - J
                for (int i = 1; i <= 25; i++)
                {
                    var cell = worksheet.Cells[i, 12];
                    cell.Formula = "=SUM(" + worksheet.Cells[i, 1].Address + ":" + worksheet.Cells[i, 10].Address + ")";
                }

                //calculate the quartile of range E1 - E25 into E27
                worksheet.Cells[27, 5].Formula = "=QUARTILE(E1:E25,1)";

                //set the total value of all cells in Sheet 2 into G27
                worksheet.Cells["G27"].Formula = "=SUM('" + worksheet2.Name + "'!" + worksheet2.Dimension.Start.Address + ":" + worksheet2.Dimension.End.Address + ")";

                //set the number of cells with content in Sheet 2, range C1 - C25 into I27
                worksheet.Cells["I27"].Formula = "=COUNT('" + excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[2].Name + "'!" + excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[2].Cells["A1:B25"] + ")";

                //calculate all the values of the formulas in the Excel file
                excelPackage.Workbook.Calculate();

                //Save the file
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo("FormulaExample.xlsx");
                excelPackage.SaveAs(fi);
            }
```

Comment: Please add an explanation